# Tikz: How to find the point on a given line segment in 3D corresponding to the intersection in the image plane?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a figure like this one but without the two gray cubes:

[image]

However, I have encountered a problem that I could not find a way to obtain the point of ``intersection" of this line segment here

[image]

and the other one there

[image]

One can notice that these two lines segments do not actually intersect. Only their projections on the image plane (aka picture plane, screen space, and so on) do. One option how I would be able to find the point on first line segment with such property is if I knew how to obtain the "eye point", yet other suggestions are welcome too.

Here is the Tikz code that has partially drawn the visible lines of the desired figure:

```tex
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
                \coordinate (right) at (5,0,0);
                \coordinate (left) at (-5,0,0);
                \coordinate (up) at (0,5,0);
                \coordinate (down) at (0,-5,0);
                \coordinate (closer) at (0,0,5);
                \coordinate (farther) at (0,0,-5);
                
                % The figure's boundary (its ``shade")
                \draw (-5,-5,5) -- ++ ($2*(up)$) -- ++ (farther) -- ++ (right) -- ++ (farther) -- ++ (right) -- ++ ($2*(down)$) -- ++ (closer) -- ++ (left) -- ++ (closer) -- ++ (left) -- cycle;
                % The groove at the bottom
                \draw (5,-5,0) -- ++ (up) -- ++ (closer) -- ++ (left) -- ++ (down);
            \end{tikzpicture}
```

and its output:

[image]

Comment: If I understand you, just write `\draw[blue] (down) -- (intersection of down--up and closer--5,0,5);`

Comment: @JuanCastaño I'm surprised that it actually works. Thank you!